# How to check user name if exist in database before committing to create user with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

Hi there is a simple login service I made with GWT, Hibernate & HSQLDB.

Right now I can create accounts, however, I need to add a functionality that will check if the username is already in the database before committing to the database.

LoginServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
public void createAccount(Account user) {

    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (InvocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Account.java

```
public class Account implements Serializable {
      Long id;
      String name;
      String password;
  public Account() {
      }
      public Account(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
      public String getPassword() {
        return password;
      }
      public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
      }
      public Long getId() {
        return id;
      }
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
      public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Query query=  session.createQuery("from Account where name=?");

Account user=(Account)query.setString(0,user.getName()).uniqueResult();
if(user!=null){
   //Do whatever you want to do
}else{
  //Insert user
}
```

Comment: @ Talha, its a syntax error, I fixed it already by re-writing the showed code above. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add something like this to your `Account` class. This ensures that the check is always performed when the model is saved, instead of having to manually add the check to every piece of code that saves the model.

```
@PrePersist
public void prepareToInsert() {
    List<User> conflicts = find("user=?").fetch();
    if (!conflicts.isEmpty()) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("username `" + name + "` is already taken");
    }
}
```

Comment: @bernace,can you elaborate how should I add this to the Account class?

Answer (score 0):

write the logic of checking already available user in set method and it should return an exception when user already exists. however i am very new to hibernate lets see whether any expert have a simple solution.